# Reference for proof complexity theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-theory

Can anyone give me some good references for proof complexity theory? I only found very few references in internet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: google: time complexity analysis pdf

Comment: @Andrianos, Thanks! I am not able to access google now, can you just load relevant pdf files, thanks a lot.

Comment: Now reposted on MO: [Is there good reference for proof complexity?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280801)